# How to unsecure a method with Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I have implemented Spring Security for a RESTful web service project. It has Request Mappings with same url patterns but with different Request Method types.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/charity/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public AccountResponseDto createAccount(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody AccountRequestDto requestDTO) {
    // some logics here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/charity/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public AccountResponseDto getAccount(HttpServletResponse response) {
    // some logics here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/charity/accounts", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateAccount(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody AccountRequestDto requestDTO){
    // some logics here
}
```

Currently all of these methods require *Authorization* to execute, but I need to remove authorization for `createAccount(...)` method. Are there annotation based solutions?

**Note:** I need a solution that will not effect to do changes for url patterns, as it will impact in many other modules.

Comment: Post your security configuration!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample configuration which would permit requests for `signup` and `about`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")  // #1
          .password("password")
          .roles("USER")
          .and()
        .withUser("admin") // #2
          .password("password")
          .roles("ADMIN","USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll();
  }
}
```

You can refer [Spring Security Java Config](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/) for detailed information.

A suggestion on your Controller. If all requests prefixed with `/charity` to be handled by CharityController, you can map requests in the below way:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/charity")
class CharityController {
            @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public AccountResponseDto getAccount(HttpServletResponse response){

            }
}
```

**Update**

The following should work for you.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, new String [] {"/charity/accounts", "/charity/people"}).permitAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks James for the quick reply but in my case I can't use the  "http      .authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/charity/accounts").permitAll();"

Because currently this same url pattern was used for other two methods as well (getAccount and updateAccount methods), which I need the authorization.

I only need to remove Authorization from createAccount method not others.

Comment: @zulox, sorry that I didn't notice the url pattern. Please find the updated answer part.

Answer (score 4):

That's why we have roles,authorizations..first we can define who can GET/PUT/POST and grant authorities to the user accordingly.

Then we can annotate as @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") on GET/PUT/POST methods accordingly.

To unsecure GET, you can add @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()") or @Secured("MY_CUSTOM_ANONYM_ROLE")

Comment: Interesting tip on `@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")`. It also allows to unsecure a method in a class that is annotated with `@Secured("..")` in case you just need to unsecure one method in the whole class.